# What are the different platforms/languages in which an app can be compiled and run on Windows without any prerequisites?

Tags: windows, winapi

What are the different platforms/languages in which an app can be compiled and run on Windows without any prerequisites? I know of .NET but it requires the specific version of .NET to be present in the Windows installation.

Comment: It depends on which version(s) of Windows you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C and C++, but Visual Studio defaults to dynamically linked library. Change the default to static and you will be fine.

That being said, ther are no compilers that come with windows. You must install a compiler to build the a program that will run everywhere after that. There are free version of the compiler in the [Platform SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx) and in [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) (Cygwin requires a dll).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual C++ as language and development tool, you may switch to Statically bound DLLs, which would produce larger binaries, but would run without any runtime-prerequisites. Visual C++ Runtimes are easily installable, can be distributed, or users may be asked to install them directly. If users are using Windows Update, they would anyhow get the latest VC runtimes.

Comment: But installing the runtime requires admin rights, which is an hidden dependency to the environment.